# Can ASP.Net application run Local Exe files on Button Click

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, permissions

I have an ASP.Net application deployed on the server. I want to know whether it will be able to access my local system exe files on button click.

I read a lot of articles regarding this on the Internet. Some are saying it is not possible for the ASP.Net application to access local programs. While some were suggesting that it depends on Permissions, identities and other things .

I tried a similar thing on my local machine but even after giving access permission to Local System, Network Service for the file and even changing the Application Pool identity to local system, i was not able to accomplish the same...

So i just want to confirm whether this thing is possible or not...

Here is the code i am trying to execute

```
 Dim pstartinfo As New ProcessStartInfo()
        Dim p As New Process()

        pstartinfo.WorkingDirectory = "D:\VS2010Projects\SignatureCaptureWindows\bin\Debug"
        pstartinfo.FileName = "SignatureCaptureWindows.exe"
        pstartinfo.CreateNoWindow = False

        p = Process.Start(pstartinfo)

        p.WaitForExit()

        If (Not p.ExitCode.Equals(0)) Then

            Response.Write("Image Successfully saved in Database with ID = " + p.ExitCode.ToString())
            DisplaySavedImage(p.ExitCode)
        Else

        End If
```

On running on locahost, it works fine.. When i deploy it on my Local IIS, it doesn't open the exe

Comment: Please clarify - what have you tried? What didn't work? Code examples will be best.

Comment: What does `SignatureCaptureWindows.exe` do?

Comment: It will launch a VB.Net windows application where user can enter there signature and save them

Comment: The user is the _web server_. What you want can't work. As I say in my answer - if you expect to interact with the `exe`, this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible and requires that the application pool user has permissions to the location of the executable and permissions to execute it.

You can use the `Process` class to execute pretty much anything (even with different user credentials if needed).

Don't forget that trying to run an application with a UI will not generally work well, as the application pool does not run in an interactive environment (so, it can't open windows and click buttons).

You should limit yourself to executables that are not interactive, as the web server will not be able to interact with windows and such.

---

In your specific scenario, where you need the user to enter their signature and it gets saved - you need them to *upload* the signature (I am assuming an image file exists already), or *create* such an image on the client side (say with `canvas` and JavaScript). You could then upload the image and save it.

Comment: You mean running exe located on the server right?Or any local computer?

Comment: @Oded Is it possible to execute the exe located on the Client at the specified path

Comment: @Mako - No. Browsers are sandboxed for security reasons (imagine that any web page could execute _anything_ on your machine when browsing!)

Comment: In my web application, we have a 'Get Signature' button which is supposed to call this exe. User can then enter there signature in the Signature PAD device, which is then stored in database as Binary Data

Comment: @Mako - In some cases this is possible, but not the general case. If you use IE and sign your JS scripts you may be able to get elevated permissions to run a local executable. Frankly, you should be rethinking your approach.

Comment: @Oded Looks like the Exe approach is not going to work. I have an ActiveX control of the same which works fine in IE. But since our application is in Firefox and it does not support ActiveX, had to try with Exe approach